# Create email addresses from first, last name

Tags: python, string, pandas

Goal: input a list of names and output list of corresponding email addresses using the structure

```
str(first_name) + '.' + str(last_name) + '@gmail.com'
```

the following function creates a list of randomly generated names...

```
import names

def fill_names(gender = 'female', n = n):
    counter = 0
    name_container = []
    while counter < n:
        name = names.get_full_name(gender = gender)
        name_container.append(name)
        counter += 1
    return name_container
```

Now that I have the names, I will put them into a dataframe with a bunch of other dataseries that I will omit here...

```
masterDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author', 'email')
masterDf.author = fill_names(n = n)
```

From here I am a bit unsure. Should i use the .split() method to split the first / last name in a for loop? Something like (this is more psuedo code)...

```
for row in masterDF.author():
    a = masterDF.author.split(' ')
    email = a[0] + '.' + a[1] + '@gmail.com'
    return email
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
masterDF['email'] = masterDF.author.str.replace('\s+', '.') + '@gmail.com'
```

Sample:

```
masterDF = pd.DataFrame({'author':['name1 surname1','name2 surname2']})

masterDF['email'] = masterDF.author.str.replace('\s+', '.') + '@gmail.com'
print (masterDF)
           author                     email
0  name1 surname1  name1.surname1@gmail.com
1  name2 surname2  name2.surname2@gmail.com
```

There is also possible use `split` solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then `join`:

```
a = masterDF.author.str.split()
masterDF['email'] = masterDF.str[0] + '.' + masterDF.str[1] + '@gmail.com'
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I like the str.replace solution